# PDF bloqueado por CORS

Tags: nodejs, angular, pdf

Estoy trabajando con la libreria PDFTron, y estoy buscando acceder a un archivo PDF que se encuentra en un servidor local creado con NodeJS.

Al intentar cargar el archivo PDF, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at urlPDF from origin urlFrontend has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Pero si intento acceder a una imagen almacenada en la misma carpeta, si la muestra la página.

Estas son las opciones que tengo para la politica CORS

```
var corsOptions ={
 origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if(whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1){
        callback(null, true);
    }
    else{
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
 },
 credentials: true,
 optionSuccessStatus: 200,
 Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method"}app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Como estas intentando acceder al archivo desde el cliente y como lo estas sirviendo en el servidor?

Comment: Estoy intentando acceder desde el cliente con la url directa de la ubicación del archivo en el backend, y en el backend el archivo lo tengo guardado en una carpeta llamada uploads que se encuentra dentro de una carpeta publica